# PictureBox change Image after table download

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am trying to download a page which will use six table. There are 6 checkbox and 6 picture box. When I click button "Download", the download starts. So each checkbox is successfully unticked on success download, but the image does not appear. The all of the images appear together after my code finishes running.

I tried a backgroundworker also, but it is not working.

```
 if (chkBoxA.Checked)
                {
                    lblInfo.Text = "Downloading table...";
                    if (DownLoadAsset() == "Success!")
                    {
                        pBoxA.Image = pbsuccess;

                        chkBoxA.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pBoxA.Image = pbfail;
                        chkBoxA.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving the app a chance to refresh the screen after the download.  The way I'd do this is:

1. Push the image downloads to a worker thread.  You'll need to use `Invoke` to set the Image property of the control from the thread.
2. After downloading an image and setting the control's `Image` property, do a `Thread.Sleep(100)` or similar to let the scheduler run the UI thread, which will do the screen update.

Comment: I had try invoke and backgroundworker but is not working. Had solve it with code application.doevent. Thanks.